# Two pieces of Code in same program HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am very new to PHP and I have two different pieces of PHP code, as shown below. I do not know how to join these two together. Each time I try to join the two codes together, it only executes the top code. Any help I could get would be great!

Here are my two pieces of code I am trying to join up:

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["title"])) {
        require "db_conn.php";
        $title = $_POST["title"];


        if (empty($title)) {
            header("Location: index.php?mess=error#popup1");
        } else {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todos(title) VALUE(?)");
            $res = $stmt->execute([$title]);

            if ($res) {
                header("Location: index.php?mess=success");
            } else {
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            $conn = null;
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php?mess=error#popup1");
    }
```

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["description"])) {
        require "db_conn.php";
        $description = $_POST["description"];


        if (empty($description)) {
            header("Location: index.php?mess=error#popup1");
        } else {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todos(description) VALUE(?)");
            $res = $stmt->execute([$description]);

            if ($res) {
                header("Location: index.php?mess=success");
            } else {
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            $conn = null;
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php?mess=error#popup1");
    }
```

Comment: that is not possible unless you have multiple `form` or do it with AJAX call

Comment: Are you asking if you can send the same form to two different targets at the same time? To do that, you need to use Ajax. When a form is submitted without Ajax, the client is redirected to the URL in the action, and a client can't be redirected to two URL's at the same time. However, I don't see why you would need to do that though, just have one of the PHP files include the other, or put all the code in one single file.

Comment: Do you really want to store the title and the description in two different records in the database? Specially without any reference between them? Or is the question actually how to store both the title and description together in the same record?